# Referencing other options in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

How would I refer to one option from another in `argparse`?

For example, I have a program which modifies existing files. I would like to have an optional argument specifying the name of the output file, which would default to the same as the input (i.e. the program would overwrite the input file by default). Here is what I have thought of so far:

```
parser.add_argument('input', )
parser.add_argument('output',
        default = sys.argv()[1],
        nargs = '?',
        )
```

But that is rather kludgey and doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would just set the value of `output` after the `parse_args()`, for example:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.output is None:
    args.output = args.input
```

The only advantage (that I can think of) to setting the default within argparse is that it can be used in the help display.  But if the user is asking for `-h` he probably isn't giving an `input` argument.  A help line to the effect: 'output default is same as the input' would be better

You might make a custom `action` for `input` that sets both `args.input` and `args.output`.  But that can be tricky.  And I don't see any advantage over the post `parse_args` logic.